# How do I port this root path with a subdomain constraint to Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

We have an app an upgrading from Rails 3.2 to 4.0.

The 3.2 version has `roots` all over routes.rb, which I ported to the new syntax, but I am not quite sure how to handle the subdomain constraint.

In 3.2:

```
  constraints(SubDomain) do
    root to: "companies#index"
    ...
  end
```

I tried to port it like the other root paths, but it looks like there is a conflict on the non-constrained root path.

Here is what I tried:

```
  constraints(SubDomain) do
    get "/", to: "companies#index", as: :root
    ...
  end
```

And the error:

> /Users/blu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:430:in
>   `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' 
>   (ArgumentError) You may have defined two routes with the same name
>   using the`:as`option, or you may be overriding a route already
>   defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can
>   restrict the routes created with`resources`as explained here: 
>   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
>   from
>   /Users/blu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.7/gems/actionpack-4.0.13/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1484:in`
>   add_route'

Any help on the correct syntax here would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Resolve the conflict by giving a different name

```
constraints(SubDomain) do
  root :to => "companies#index", :as=> :subdomain_root
   ...
end
```